# Select box issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I am using simple html code to display a select box when ever i use id attribute for select tag it does not display any item in the list but when ever i remove id attribute it works. but surprisingly the same code works fine in Firefox and Google chrome.

```
<select id="class_renew" name="class_renew" onchange="class_check()" style="width:310px; height:35px; padding:8px; margin-left:95px;">
<option value="0">Select Your Class</option>
                        </select>
```

Help from any one will be appreciated.

Java Script Code

```
function classInput(data){
    var category_vals = document.getElementById("class_renew");

    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

            category_vals.innerHTML+="<option value='"+data[i].cat+"'>PK-"+data[i].cat+"</option>"
        }
```

}

Comment: an id attribute has nothing to do with being able to (or unable to) show options in a select. You need to show whatever JS code is building that select.

Comment: I think you are using this id to remove any child nodes or child elements. But, if that works in Google Chrome and Firefox, then you're actually doing something wrong somewhere. Share the JS and HTML code related to this SELECT statement..

Comment: i have shared complete html code for select box and the java script code for the same as well

Answer (score 0):

IDs must match. "class_renew" and "categroy_renew" [sic] are not the same, so of course it won't work ;)

EDIT:

Rather than using `.innerHTML`, why not do things properly?

```
category_vals.appendChild(new Option("PK-"+data[i].cat,data[i].cat));
```

This ensures that you won't have any problems if, for example, any of the items have an apostrophe in them.

Comment: sorry its class i have changed now. Check it out